# Как вывести данные из бд, при этом убрать кое какие символы

Tags: php, mysql

я все настроил все подключил но мне надо чтобы выводимая информация редактировалась. Сейчас объясню на примере.
У меня выводится вот так

```
<img src=\"https://stmed.net/sites/default/files/video-game-hd-wallpapers-33874-9226532.jpg\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"\">
```

А я хочу чтобы выводилась только ссылка на картинку тоесть

```
https://stmed.net/sites/default/files/video-game-hd-wallpapers-33874-9226532.jpg
```

Но при этом чтобы в бд не менялись значения.

Comment: Нужно привести пример значения в бд и вывода на страницу

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте разбивку выводимого текста:

```
$source = '<img src=\"https://stmed.net/sites/default/files/video-game-hd-wallpapers-33874-9226532.jpg\" class=\"fr-fic fr-dib\" alt=\"\">';
$source = explode('\"', $source);
$source = $source[1];
echo $source;
```